# Laravel 5 Elixir source and output pathing

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm having trouble understanding Laravel 5's elixir pathing.  In my project, I have multiple css files (bootstrap, plugins, theme etc) and javascript files stored under:

```
resources/assets/css/<my css files>
resources/assets/js/<my javascript files>
```

I simply want to combine and version all styles and scripts and place them in my public directory.  I believe the default output directly is:

```
public/build/css/app-xxxxxxxx.css
public/build/js/app-xxxxxxxx.js
```

(Where `xxxxxxxx` is the checksum using the `version` method)

What should my `gulpfile.js` look like to achieve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full path on the name or set the third parameter as default path. Examples (works with scripts or css):

```
mix.stylesIn('resources/assets/css', 'public/css/all.css');
```

Since there is a bug where you can't use the output of a somethingAll to concatenate with something else, I use this instead (note the wildcard):

```
mix.scripts(['maskedinput.js',
        'blockui.js',
        'user/*.js'],
   'public/js/user.js', 'resources/assets/js/');
```

First parameter is the input files, second is the output file, third is the input's default path.

To version just call it on the file path.

```
mix.version("public/js/user.js");
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I did not know about the wildcard.  My final gulpfile.js ended up like this:


`elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts('*.js', 'public/assets/js/application.js', 'resources/assets/js/');
    mix.styles('*.css', 'public/assets/css/application.css', 'resources/assets/css');
    mix.version(['public/assets/js/application.js', 'public/assets/css/application.css']);
});`